# Interpolation with SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

I want to use Scipy-> interpolate->interp2d. Result of interpolation is correct, but why result is saved in list three times? I used next script:

`from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np`

```
def main(): 
    x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    y = np.array([1, 2])
    z = np.array([[4,4,6,6],[6, 6,12, 12]])
    f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear', copy = False)

    xi = np.array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5])
    yi = np.array([1.5,1.5,1.
```

Result is:

```
zi =[[ 5.  7.  9.][ 5.  7.  9.] [ 5.  7.  9.]]
```

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your input arrays `x,y,z` need to be of identical shape. In your case one has four entries, one has two entries, and the other one is two dimensional with four entries. This will trigger numpy broadcasting. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html